# Should [emr] be a synonym for [amazon-emr]?

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I don't have the points in either tag to suggest an alias. But I'm pretty sure they're the same thing.

What about other [amazon-*] tags?

Comment: Why not just good ol' retaggin?

Comment: There's a few hundred of both. Can it be done in bulk?

Comment: Shouldn't newer questions be a duplicate of older ones?