# Cleanup of [amazon-emr], [elastic-map-reduce] and [emr]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Current counts:

- 731 x [amazon-emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-emr)
- 458 x [elastic-map-reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-map-reduce)
- 931 x [emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr)

Previous requests:

- [Merge [emr] into [amazon-emr]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343102/merge-emr-into-amazon-emr)
- [Delete [emr] - it's a duplicate of [amazon-emr]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334617/delete-emr-its-a-duplicate-of-amazon-emr)
- [Should [emr] be a synonym for [amazon-emr]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334492/should-emr-be-a-synonym-for-amazon-emr)
- [elastic-map-reduce] -> [emr] [synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elastic-map-reduce/synonyms)

**Suggested:**

- Master tag: `[amazon-emr]`
- Synonyms: `[emr]` and `[elastic-map-reduce]`

This matches the existing `amazon-*` tag format.

I'm unable to create the suggested synonyms due to the [existing synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elastic-map-reduce/synonyms).